# Get property names from lambda function

Tags: c#, lambda

ASP.NET MVC somehow takes the names of properties from constructions like:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
```

I want to implement this magic too to decrease the magic strings count in my project. Could you help me with it? Simple example:

```
// that's how it works in my project
this.AddModelStateError("Password", "Password must not be empty"); 

// desired result
this.AddModelStateError(x => x.Password, "Password must not be empty");
```

Comment: have you looked at how the mvc framework does it? the source is freely available.

Comment: didn't know about it. Thanks. I'll try to find it.

Comment: Find the solution in ModelMetaData.FromLambdaExpression :) thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asp MVC's `LabelFor` helper takes an `Expression<Func<TModel, Value>>`. This expression can be used to retrieve the property info that the `Func<TModel,Value>` points to, which in turn can have it's name retrieved through `PropertyInfo.Name`.

Asp MVC then assigns the `name` attribute on a HTML tag to equal this name. So if you select a property with `LabelFor` called `Id`, you end up with `<label name='Id'/>`.

In order to get the `PropertyInfo` from the `Expression<Func<TModel,Value>>`, you could look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/672212/1073868), which uses the following code:

```
public PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TSource, TProperty>(
    TSource source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyLambda)
{
    Type type = typeof(TSource);

    MemberExpression member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
            "Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.",
            propertyLambda.ToString()));

    PropertyInfo propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propInfo == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
            "Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.",
            propertyLambda.ToString()));

    if (type != propInfo.ReflectedType &&
        !type.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType))
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
            "Expresion '{0}' refers to a property that is not from type {1}.",
            propertyLambda.ToString(),
            type));

    return propInfo;
}
```